# put a delay in a class that implements runnable java

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I want to sleep a thread but I can't figure it out I tried with Thread.sleep and with Timer but I can't achieve this is my code:

```
public class HiloEscrituraSerial implements Runnable{
    private volatile boolean inicio = false;
    OutputStream out;
    int contador =0;
    private Vector<byte[]> datos;

    public HiloEscrituraSerial(){}

    public void run(){
        Pruebas.lecturaCompleta = false;
        Timer t = new Timer(10, null);
        t.setDelay(3000);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();

        System.out.println(FrmPrincipal.linea() +" Comenzando a enviar la prueba al    certificador");
        while(inicio){
            try{
                for(int i = 0;i<datos.size();i++){
                    //se deja un delay para que envie los comandos cada 0.1 seg.
                    /*
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex)
                        System.out.println(FrmPrincipal.linea() + " Error al dormir el hilo. "+Constantes.MENSAJE_MANUAL);
                       //Logger.getLogger(HiloEscrituraSerial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }*/
                    this.out.write(datos.get(i));
                    System.out.println(FrmPrincipal.linea() + " La prueba fue enviada al certificador");
                }
                //cuando termine el de enviar los comandos finalizar el ciclo
                inicio = false;
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(FrmPrincipal.linea() + " Error en envio de datos al certificador. "+Constantes.MENSAJE_MANUAL);
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        t.stop();
        Pruebas.lecturaCompleta = true;
    }

    public void setOutput(OutputStream out){
        this.out = out;
    }

    void setDatos(Vector<byte[]> comando){
        datos = comando;
    }

    public void setBegins(){
        inicio = true;
    }

    public void setClose(){
        inicio = false;
    }
}
```

I need sleep the thread by 20 miliseconds for write a again in the serial port.
somebody could help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code and can't test it either, but the following works:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (;;) {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                    System.out.println("Executed");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Update your post to a simplified example (without usage of external classes and with English-named identifiers) if you want to get more help.